# Is there a catch to PayPal's Premier account type?

Tags: paypal

I clicked the "upgrade account" button on PayPal and upgraded my account to Premier by accident, thinking that I would be able to see the fee or restriction by pressing Continue enough, but nothing ever popped up and I couldn't find this information in the links provided. What is a Premier account's catch?? Do I have to pay something ever? If so, how could I downgrade back to a normal account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the different between Personal Accounts and Premier/Business Accounts

[Comparison of Personal and Premier/Business Paypal accounts](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/gen/fees-outside)

And from [Answers.com](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_downgrade_a_PayPal_account) here's how to downgrade your account (only once allowed):

1. Log into your PayPal account, select
   Contact Us, then Email Us.
2. Under Select a Topic, choose "My
   Account" and then "Downgrade
   Account" (if available) or "Changing
   Account Type".
3. Summarise you question in box 3 -
   e.g. I would like to downgrade my
   account - and use the Continue
   button.

*You can only downgrade your account once.*

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, the PayPal's Premier Account has no periodic charges.  It is free, and it is linked to a post-paid or pre-paid credit card.

I am owner of a PayPal's Premier Account, too.

I am not sure is it possibile to downgrade to a normal account.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I never made use of the Premier features and got tired of paying fees when a friend or family member sent me money, so I wanted to go back to the Personal account.

I was able to downgrade my Premier account back to a personal account, but they said it is something you can only do once. Not a big deal, but if you end up with a Business account and a Premier account, you will have to close one in order to have a Personal account again since you are only allowed to hold 2 accounts.

Answer (score -2):

So this is how it will work:

Go to “Help” on top of the page, then “Contact Us” on bottom right and then “Send an email”. Then type topic as “Account settings,” then subtopic as “Closing account”.

Comment: iT WORKED FOR ME..

Comment: This has already long been answered. Also, your Caps Lock is on.